# Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `wt`: geom_net function incompatible with new dplyr version

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using `geom_net` function from `geom_net` R package.

Until few months ago I could use the `geom_net` function with non problems, but now I get the following error:

```
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `wt`.
x could not find function "n"
ℹ Input `wt` is `n()`.
ℹ The error occured in group 1:
```

My understanding of the error is that the `summarise()` function of `dplyr` package no longer uses the argument `wt=n()` as also specified in the `dlyr` R package recent update.

The problem is that `geom_net` uses a (now) old version of `summarise()` which is now incompatible with the new `dplyr` version.

Do you have any suggestion on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's [exactly one line](https://github.com/sctyner/geomnet/blob/ca44ee77d59f6532b7ab29fcea8c724c5831f4c1/R/stat-net.r#L76) in the `geom_net` source code that uses `dplyr::summarise()` with the `wt` argument:

```
edges <- dplyr::summarise(edges, wt = n())
```

And the `dplyr` [change log](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#dplyr-1-0-1-2020-07-31) notes that `wt` is not replaced by anything, you can just omit it.

> Use of wt = n() is now deprecated; now just omit the wt argument.

You should be able to just modify your local version of the `geom_net` package.  Remove the `wt` argument from that single line.

(Note that this won't necessarily guarantee that `geom_net` runs without error, just that it resolves the specific issue you're asking about here.)

Comment: It worked..in addition to what you suggested I had to delete few lines (82 - 87; and 89) from the 'change log' notes.